# Adding full-page illustrations before chapters in classic-thesis

Tags: graphics, classicthesis

I use classic-thesis, and I would like to do the following:
each chapter should begin on an odd page (right on a dual-page view), and on the left page should be displayed a picture I choose.

would that be possible?

thank you

EDIT:

with classicthesis, this will put title pages on the right pages instead of the left :

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper,twoside,openright,titlepage]{scrreprt}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\ChapImage{\huge image page -- should be on the left!}
\newcommand*\Invcleardoublepage{
\clearpage\if@twoside
  \ifodd\c@page \null\newpage\if@twocolumn\null%
  \newpage\fi\fi\fi
}
\renewcommand\chapter{%
  \if@openright
    \ifodd\c@page{\clearpage}\else{\Invcleardoublepage}\fi
    {
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \ChapImage
    \clearpage
    }
  \else
    \clearpage
  \fi
  \thispagestyle{\chapterpagestyle}%
  \global\@topnum\z@
  \@afterindentfalse
  \secdef\@chapter\@schapter
}
\makeatother

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                  % la codifica dei font
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{changepage,calc}                % per impostare i margini del frontespizio
\usepackage{lipsum}                       % genera testo fittizio

\usepackage{classicthesis-ldpkg}          % carica molti pacchetti utili a ClassicThesis

\usepackage[eulerchapternumbers,%         % numeri dei capitoli in Euler
            subfig,%                      % compatibilità con subfig
            beramono,%                    % Bera Mono come font a spaziatura fissa
            eulermath,%                   % AMS Euler come font per la matematica
            pdfspacing%                   % migliora il riempimento di riga con PDFLaTeX
            ]{classicthesis}              % lo stile ClassicThesis

%\usepackage[english]{arsclassica}         % modifica alcuni aspetti di ClassicThesis

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{titlepage}
\changetext{}{}{}{((\paperwidth  - \textwidth) / 2) - \oddsidemargin - \hoffset - 1in}{}
\null\vfill
\large
\sffamily

{Title page}

\vfill
\end{titlepage}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\pagestyle{scrheadings} 

\clearpage
\lipsum[1-4]

\clearpage
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents
\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}} 

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{First chapter}
\lipsum[1-10]
\chapter{Second chapter}
\lipsum[1-8]
\chapter{Third chapter}
\lipsum[1-10]
\chapter{Fourth chapter}
\lipsum[1-8]

\end{document}
```

Comment: maybe you could try to redefine `\chapter` to, instead of doing a `\cleardoublepage`, do a `\clearpage\thispagestyle{empty}\includegraphics[<options>]{path/to/image}`, but this is just a long shot

Comment: There is a problem: if the previous chapter ends in an even page there's no place for the picture! In this case one should add a blank page, the picture and finally the chapter!

Comment: I think there's a confusion here: what exactly do you mean with odd page? I assumed you meant an odd-numbered page.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The basic idea is to redefine `\chapter` as defined in the corresponding `.cls` file. I used `scrbook.cls`, but the modifications needed are clear *mutatis mutandis* for other classes). To guarantee that all chapters will begin in an odd numbered page and that the images get included in the (even numbered) page before the beginning of the chapter, I used an auxiliary command `\Invcleardoublepage` that acts as an "inverse" to `\cleardoublepage`: it flushes all material and starts a new page, but starts in a new even numbered page.

Finally, with the help of the `xparse` package I defined a `\MyChapter` command with one optional arguments (the entry for the ToC) and two mandatory arguments (the title of the chapter, and the name of the image to be used).

```
\documentclass[11pt,a5paper,footinclude=true,headinclude=true]{scrbook}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[linedheaders]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand\ChapImage{}

\makeatletter
% A command that acts as an "inverse" cleardoublepage:
% flush all material and start a new page, start new even numbered page
\newcommand*\Invcleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside
  \ifodd\c@page \null\newpage\if@twocolumn\null%
  \newpage\fi\fi\fi
}
\renewcommand\chapter{%
  \if@openright
    \ifodd\c@page\clearpage\else\Invcleardoublepage\fi% NEW
    \thispagestyle{empty}\ChapImage\clearpage
  \else\clearpage
  \fi
  \thispagestyle{\chapterpagestyle}%
  \global\@topnum\z@
  \@afterindentfalse
  \secdef\@chapter\@schapter
}
\makeatother
\DeclareDocumentCommand\MyChapter{omm}{%
  \renewcommand\ChapImage{\includegraphics[width=.95\textwidth,height=.95\textheight]{#3}}
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
    {\chapter{#2}}{\chapter[#1]{#2}}
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\MyChapter[Entry in ToC]{Test Chapter with an Image}{image1}
\lipsum[1-3]

\MyChapter{Another Test Chapter with another Image}{image3}
\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

I used the `demo` option for `graphicx` to make my example compilable for everyone, do *not* use that option in your actual code.

If the document uses \part, then the following redefinition (or a similar one if the class is not `scrbook`) should also be added to the preamble:

```
\renewcommand\part{%
  \if@openright
    \ifodd\c@page\clearpage\else\Invcleardoublepage\fi% NEW
  \else\clearpage
  \fi
  \thispagestyle{\partpagestyle}%
  \if@twocolumn
    \onecolumn
    \@tempswatrue
  \else
    \@tempswafalse
  \fi
  \partheadstartvskip
  \vbox to\z@{\vss\use@preamble{part@o}\strut\par}%
  \vskip-\baselineskip\nobreak%
  \secdef\@part\@spart
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But when I do this with classic thesis, it does not work properly: if ChapImage is not defined, it correctly displays a blank page at the left and the chapter page at the right, but if I define ChapImage, it shows a blank page at the left, the image at the right, then it starts the chapter on the next left page (perhaps because the chapter command has been redefined in classic-thesis). Do you have some idea what the problem might be?

Comment: And why was the redefinition of part needed? (I don't use parts in my manuscript)

Comment: @oulipo: Please add to your question a minimal version of your document showing that my solution doesn't work as expected: as you can see, my example code do works and it uses the `classicthesis` package. And I redefined `\part` because I couldn't possible know if you would use it or not.

Comment: @oulipo: I improved the code. There's no need to redefine commands anymore, and the new definition is more flexible.

Comment: I think I understood what was wrong: Invcleardouble page selects the first even page to put its content, but even in the sense that the corresponding LaTeX page is even, not that the PDF page is even ; if for instance my PhD begins with an odd number of "i, ii, ..." pages, then all the following "1, 2, ..." pages of LaTeX are shifted (eg. odd LaTeX page are put on even PDF pages), and thus the resulting PDF file won't have the chapter page where  I  want it. Do you know how we can correct that?

Comment: I added a reply with a sample LaTeX file using the proposed solution that puts everything on right pages rather than left

Comment: could you reproduce the bug?

Comment: @oulipo: Not exactly with your code, but with a slight modification (adding some more text with lipsum before the chapters). Now I understand what you are trying to achieve. I'm kind of busy, but when I have some time I'll think about a possible solution.

Comment: thanks alot if you can help me! (I'd like to just be able to add a \clearpage before and "fix that manually" but it does not seem to work -- and I have to publish my PhD soon..). Hope you'll find a way to make it function properly and simply!

Comment: @oulipo: I haven't found an automatic solution. If you want to add some page(s) manually, you can use something like `\clearpage
\mbox{}
\clearpage` in the appropriate locations.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina how would this work together with the memoir package?

Answer (score 7):

I would define a command that would call both the image as well as the chapter,

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}
\makeatletter
\def\chapter{\clearpage\thispagestyle{plain}\global\@topnum
   \z@\@afterindentfalse
   \secdef\@chapter\@schapter
}
\makeatother
\title{My Picture Chapters}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\newcommand{\chapterwithpic}[3][]{%
  \includegraphics[width=1.2\textwidth]{./graphics/#3}
  \chapter[#1]{#2}
}

\chapterwithpic[option]{Amato}{pic}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: +1 but I think it is better to make the optional argument as `#1` as in `\newcommand{\MyChapterPic}[3][]{...}`.

Comment: @xport ... agreed, won't you please edit my answer? I am off to work.

Comment: @Yiannis: well done.

Comment: Thank you, but actually this won't show the picture on the left page and the chapter on the right page since the chapter command will do a cleardoublepage before

Comment: @oulipo This was a quick way to show you how to approach the problem. I did use the oneside option. You can test for odd/even page before the image insert and either issue a pagebreak to force the image to go to the next page on the left or if not necessary continue with just inserting it. This way the `chapter` will always land on the right side. If you don't get it right let me know and I will post the code later on in the day. Busy day:)

Comment: @yiannis Please do post the code, I would be interested!

Comment: @oulipo added a bit of a hack, see if this works for you.

Comment: @Yiannis: but, using your code, there's no guarantee that every chapter will begin in an odd-numbered page.